# Is there a reason why the BufferedWriter writes sumbols instead of numbers?

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I am trying to write to a file a 2 dimensional array from numbers, but it only writes (SOH) for 1, (ENO) for 5 and a blank space for 0(NUL).
I got those letters from NotePad++

```
    int[][] array= new int[][]
    {
          { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
          { 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
          { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
          { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
    };
     String level = "Level.txt";
     try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(level))) {
         for(int i=0;i<masiv1.length;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++)
             {
                 writer.write(array[i][j]);
             }
             writer.write("\n");
         }
     }
```

I want to write the numbers to the file if possible.

Comment: Some advice: read the documentation of the methods you call; know what they are doing. If you hover on the method your IDE should show it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling [`Writer.write(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(int)) which writes a single character to the writer.

If you want the *string representation* of a number, you need to make sure you convert to a string first and call `Writer.write(String)`. The easiest way of doing that is to call `String.valueOf` to perform the conversion:

```
writer.write(String.valueOf(array[i][j]));
```

Comment: Thank you! It fixed my problem! Thank you very much!